# Unable to set pom version in version.txt file during mvn clean install

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to write a version.txt file, that will contain the version number in the pom file.  Following information I found on this site, I have the following:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.user.testcase</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

And my text file, version.txt, has:

```
Version: ${version}
```

After using `mvn clean install`, the tar file is created, and I untar it to see if the version is in the text file.  However, the file is unchanged, with `${version}` instead of 1.0.

I'm doing this in preparation for a script to ensure the correct version of a project are Are there any other methods to do this?